# Why isfile is not displaying all the files

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I have this simple Python code:

```
import os
print [f for f in os.listdir('C:\Users\g514549\Desktop\MyFolder') if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Now, if I open the directory, I get all the files as below:

[image: Snapshot of the directory content]

But when I run the python script, I get an empty string, indicating all the files are returning `False`:

But when I change the directory like this:

```
import os
print [f for f in os.listdir('C:\Users\g514549\Desktop\C++') if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

it shows all the files properly. 
The 2nd Folder content is below.

[image: 2nd Directory Link]

**What is happening ?**
I have tried deleting all the files in the 1st directory and create some dummy files with different text editor and with different encoding, but nothing is working.

**Note** *I can only get True for any exe file in the first folder*

**Note 2** *It is not a possible duplicate of the reported question. This one is different*

Comment: @Hacketo Thanks for the answer but it is not a possible duplicate..In other question, the OP had problem with the file path. Here I have no problem with one path but problem with the other path. Here I am not talking about the file names in the path at all

Comment: Try to add full path for both, only one is working because the script path might be the same as the folder you check, "access.py" or "test.py"? (So its a duplicate)

Comment: is it normal that in the first case all files seem empty? Very strange. Is it link? Are you sure you have all right on theses files? Try to launch cmd with admin right and relaunch your script.

Comment: @A.H He probably just made a few empty files as a test.

Comment: And the result of [(f,os.path.isfile(f)) for f in os.listdir('C:\Users\g514549\Desktop\MyFolder')] ? Because here, we can't be sure you are in the good directory or the loop try all files

Comment: Also, you should have double backslashes in your strings, since they are not raw: 'C:\\Users\\g514549\\Desktop\\MyFolder'

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate. The reason why it works in the second case is that `C:\Users\g514549\Desktop\C++` is the working directory in which you are executing your script (I'm guessing it's the one called `test.py`...). As in the other question, you need to pass the *full* path to `os.path.isfile`, not just the filename.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `'C:\Users\g514549\Desktop\C++'` is your current path.

Nothing in `/tmp`:

```
>>> len([f for f in os.listdir('/tmp') if os.path.isfile(f)])
0
```

But when I create the full path:

```
>>> len([f for f in os.listdir('/tmp') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/tmp', f))])
2
```

Changing to `/tmp`:

```
cd /tmp
```

Makes it work without the full path:

```
>>> len([f for f in os.listdir('/tmp') if os.path.isfile(f)])
2
```

To be on the save side, always create the full path. You never know if the current working directory is changing for reason outside your control.

**Note**:  On Windows always use raw strings when copy-pasting paths:

```
r'C:\Users\g514549\Desktop\C++'
```

to avoid effects caused by `\n`, `\t`, or other formatting characters.

Comment: Nice observation..thanks..but can you please tell me that when I had one `.exe` file in the first directory, even without switching to that directory, it shows that `.exe` file but not any other files.?

Comment: Maybe you have a file with the same name in your current directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk` to show all files.

```
import os
print [f for (dir, subdirs, fs) in os.walk('.') for f in fs]
```